# Repository в Hibernate 5

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-jpa

Начинаю разбираться с Hibernate 5 и не понятна суть работы с бд.

Взял пример в интернете - код ниже.

Не могу одного понять. Смысл создавать service если он попросту дублирует repository по сути. 
Подскажите как правильно такое реализовывать. Вообще реализовывать DAO. Что касается Entity мне более менее понятно, как описывать и т.д. но вот сам этот процесс не очень.

Хочется научится правильно делать.

Спасибо.

```
public interface UserRepository {
    UserEntity save(UserEntity car);
    void update(UserEntity user);
    List<UserEntity> getAll();
    List<UserEntity> getAllByFirstName(String firstName);
    List<UserEntity> getAllByLastName(String lastName);
    List<UserEntity> getAllByGender(String gender);
    UserEntity getById(Long id);
    void remove(Long id);
}


@Repository
@Transactional()
public class UserRepositoryImpl  implements UserRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserEntity save(UserEntity user) {
        if(user.getId() != null){
            return entityManager.merge(user);
        } else {
            entityManager.persist(user);
            return user;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(UserEntity user) {

    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> getAll() {
        CriteriaQuery<UserEntity> criteria = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(UserEntity.class);
        criteria.select(criteria.from(UserEntity.class));
        return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> getAllByFirstName(String firstName) {
         ...
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> getAllByLastName(String lastName) {
         ...
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> getAllByGender(String gender) {
         ...
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity getById(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(UserEntity.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Long id) {
        UserEntity user = getById(id);
        if(user != null) {
            entityManager.remove(user);
        }
    }
}


public interface UserService {
    UserEntity save(UserEntity userEntityy);
    List<UserEntity> getAll();
    UserEntity getById(long id);
    void remove(long id);
}


@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserEntity save(UserEntity userEntityy) {
        return userRepository.save(userEntityy);
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> getAll() {
        return userRepository.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity getById(long id) {
        return userRepository.getById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(long id) {
        userRepository.remove(id);

    }
}
```

Comment: Это вопрос относится не к Hibernate, а к теории проектирования, в частности многослойной архитектуры.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev не соглашусь. Это касается работы hibernate - как его использовать и т.д.

Comment: Вы разве аннотации `@Repository` и `@Service` из пакета `org.hibernate` импортировали? Обе они относятся к Spring, а не к Hibernate. Hibernate можно использовать и без сервиса, и без репозитория.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev окей. добавил в вопрос метки. Но суть та же. Общаться с бд я буду через хибер.

Comment: Смысл раздилять на repository & service layer имеит смысл даже если в начале проектирования вы этого не видите. Обычный пример, вам надо удалить пользователя в 4 разных методах. 1 - Удалить только пользователя, 2,3 - удалить пользователя и отправить notification. 4 - удалить пользавателя и все его child зависимости. Самый лучший вариант для этого сделать отдельные методы в service layer где все будет понятно изначально из сигнатуры метода и одновременно вы придерживайтесь принципов DRY & KISS. Если же вы не будете использавать service layer ваша архитектура будет усложняться с каждой итерацией